# How to track the last transfers of a token in web3.py

Tags: python, web3py, bscscan

I'm using web3.py. There is something i want to learn. How can I track the latest transfers of a token?

[Latest Transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smxbk.png)

I need to follow the part seen in the picture above live. New transfers do not appear unless the page is refreshed.Being able to do it over Web3 is my priority. I'm open to alternative suggestions.

https://bscscan.com/token/0x5774b2fc3e91af89f89141eacf76545e74265982

Answer (score 0):

The thing you can do is create a filter and track contract events.

```
filter = web3.eth.filter({'address': token_address, 'topics': ['0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',]})
while True:
    print(filter.get_new_entries())
```